# Best practices for testing AngularJS + D3 applications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I recently started to develop an application using AngularJS + D3. However, I cannot think of good ways to test this application. For example, the code below draws a circle. How am I supposed to test that?

```
app.directive('firstTry', function () {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var sampleSVG = d3.select(element[0])
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100);

        sampleSVG.append("circle")
            .style("stroke", "gray")
            .style("fill", "white")
            .attr("r", 40)
            .attr("cx", 50)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
            .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E'
    };
});
```

A more general question will be as stated in the title: What are best practices to develop a testable application using AngularJS + D3? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could inspect the DOM and verify that there's a circle with the parameters you expect.